# SQL Trim a leading character from a column while also selecting other columns

Tags: sql

I have a SQL statement where one of the columns holds currency values in string format. For example... $22.50

I need to trim that dollar sign while still selecting other columns.

Here is my statement...

```
    SELECT a.txtLineNbr, a.txtItemNumber, a.txtCustomerItem, a.txtDescription, a.nbrQtyOrdered, a.curSellPrice, b.series, c.picid 
      FROM ejn_webOrderLines a 
INNER JOIN ejn_ExpandedDescriptions b 
        ON b.txtItemA = a.txtItemNumber 
INNER JOIN ejn_series c 
        ON c.series = b.series 
       AND a.nbrQtyOrdered > 0 
       AND a.SessionID = @SessionID 
     ORDER BY a.txtLineNbr
```

the column is `a.curSellPrice`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `replce` function , replace(a.curSellPrice, '$', '')

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace `$` in query , it will help you to remove `$` sign from the value.

```
SELECT a.txtLineNbr, a.txtItemNumber, a.txtCustomerItem, a.txtDescription, a.nbrQtyOrdered, 
       replace(a.curSellPrice,'$','') as curSellPrice, b.series, c.picid 
FROM ejn_webOrderLines a 
INNER JOIN ejn_ExpandedDescriptions b 
ON b.txtItemA = a.txtItemNumber 
INNER JOIN ejn_series c 
ON c.series = b.series 
AND a.nbrQtyOrdered > 0 
AND a.SessionID = @SessionID 
ORDER BY a.txtLineNbr
```